# Function Call not working in let statement inside linq

Tags: c#, linq

```
    double Percentage = 80;
    var MatchingTransactions = (from RowT in dtTransactionsList.AsEnumerable()
                                from RowN in dtNameList.AsEnumerable()
    let cust_match_percentage = ReturnSimilarityPercentage() //returns double
    let rec_match_percentage = ReturnSimilarityPercentage() //returns double
    where (cust_match_percentage >= Percentage || rec_match_percentage >= Percentage)
    select new{
    trn_id = Convert.ToInt64(RowT["trn_id"]),
    matching_name = "",
    matching_percentage = (cust_match_percentage > rec_match_percentage) ? cust_match_percentage : rec_match_percentage}).Distinct();
    public double ReturnSimilarityPercentage(){return 86.345;}
```

The function `ReturnSimilarityPercentage()` is not getting executed.

Comment: Show us the code of `ReturnSimilarityPercentage`...

Comment: It is not called due to deferred enumeration. Call an extension on `MatchingTransactions` that enumerates the results (`.ToList()` for example)

Comment: Thanks dude.. Daniel Park
It Worked!! Thank You Very much.